# Fastest way to call .map on reversed array JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse

Basically what title says: I want to be able to call `.map` on a reversed array, but I'm afraid that it would be too slow since I have to do this operation numerous times.

I know that the following method works:

```
let arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let rev_wrapped = arr.slice(0).reverse().map(item => `wrapped: ${item}`);
```

where `rev_wrapped` turns out to be:

```
[
  'wrapped: 5',
  'wrapped: 4',
  'wrapped: 3',
  'wrapped: 2',
  'wrapped: 1'
]
```

I was wondering if there is any faster way to do this, since `.reverse()` reverses the array entirely, while I just need to read data in reverse order.

In case this isn't possible, I would also be ok with a data structure which allows me to insert elements at the start without too much computational cost (since something like `arr.splice(0,0,new_item)` would rearrange the array completely at every insertions).

Comment: Why not simply use a good old `for(var i = (arr.length - 1); i >= 0; i--){ }` loop here? it will be faster and use less memory than any functional approach. Js is not a pure functional language, I wonder where this trend to use all functional comes from

Comment: "*I'm afraid that it would be too slow*" - instead of worrying, first **measure** whether it actually is "too slow" or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspired by the other answers, I just ended up doing something like:

```js
let arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let wrapped = arr.map((_, i) => `wrapped ${arr[arr.length - 1 - i]}`);

console.log(wrapped);
```

If you are looking for a simple `for` implementation, check [T.J. Crowder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76968422/12904316), if you want a less compact and more explicit implementation, check
[Vivick's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76968408/12904316)

Answer (score 5):

Your current code makes three passes through the array (`slice`, to make the copy; `reverse`, to reverse it; and `map` to map it). **If** performance is a concern and you have found that your current approach is too slow (I suggest measuring, not speculating), you're probably best off just using a simple loop:

```js
let arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let rev_wrapped = new Array(arr.length);
for (let i = 0, n = arr.length - 1; n >= 0; --n, ++i) {
    rev_wrapped[i] = `wrapped: ${arr[n]}`;
}
console.log(rev_wrapped);
```

That just makes a single pass through the array.

Normally, `new Array` is an anti-pattern, but in modern JavaScript engines `new Array(5)` will typically pre-allocate storage (something I learned recently and was surprised by).

Comment: Accepted you answer since it's the most complete. I ended up doing a simple `let result = arr.map((_, i) => \`wrapped ${arr[arr.length - 1 - i]}\`);` because from my local testing was faster and shorter (I just need it to populate and render a table).

Comment: @master_roby3 - **OMG**, I can't believe I wrote the entire `Array.from` part without realizing how over-complicated it was; of course just use `map` instead (if you don't use a `for`). I claim lack of coffee and a bad night's sleep. :-) I suggest posting your own answer (entirely fine here on SO) and accepting that instead.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple helper function (or inline its implementation wherever you want to use it, if needed for chaining purposes).

```js
function reversedMap(arr, mapper) {
  const { length } = arr;
  return arr.map((_, i) => mapper(arr[length - 1 - i]));
}

let arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(reversedMap(arr, item => `wrapped: ${item}`));
```

Comment: Can be further shortened, since the `map` callback already receives the array, so you can directly decorate the callback with one that processes in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

I think valid approach is by using `Array.prototype.reduceRight`:

```js
const arr  = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
      result = arr.reduceRight((a, item) => ([...a, `wrapped: ${item}`]), []);

console.log(result);
```